# Is DirectShow.net C# library is working with windows 10 and visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, directshow.net

Can I able to develop application that get bitmaps from video camera that attached to USB 3.0 using DirectShow.Net C# library on windows 10 and visual studio 2013?

Comment: Why do you think that would not work?

Comment: You can download both VS2013 and DShow.NET, build samples and ensure you're okay (and you really are).

Comment: @RomanR. Yes I have try it and it work, even i am able to get basic video frames , but I am facing this issue,when this statement IMediaControl.Run();, it shows me error like "The file %2 could not be processed by the application %1 because it requires Indeo® Decoders of type %3". And Still BufferCB receiving the frame data. Do you have any idea regarding this?